# Problem sorting a view based on a text field with numeric values in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

An existing Lotus Notes database form has a text field whic contains a numeric value. I am trying create a view to sort on this field but the result is coming up as follows

99
1000
1002
1003
101
1011

Is there any way to convert the field so I can sort numerically. Lotus Notes 6.5.

Comment: Please post the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562/1228)

Answer (score 2):

In the column formula, convert your item to a number using

```
@TextToNumber( itemname )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried @TextToNumber and I get @Error.

Comment: You'll get an error if the item can't be converted to a number.  Does it happen on all records or just some?  You can override inconsistencies by first converting the item value to text, and then converting that to a number using `@TextToNumber( @Text( itemname ) )`

Comment: Hi Ken. The @Error is returned for all rows in the view. I tried @Text and the result is blank so @TextToNumber(@Text) also returns @Error.

Comment: You tried @Text and included the name of your field in parenthesis, for example `@Text( field )` and everything showed up blank?  If so, take a look at the field type.  Go to any view, select a document, then click File > Document Properties and click the second tab.  Then find your field name and look to see what the data type is.

Comment: @Text on a text field should show the value, unless the field is a rich text field.  You are replacing "itemname" with the actual name of your field, right?

Comment: plain old @texttonumber is prone to errors if the value cannot be translated to a number. Judging by the dialogue with Sheila, she needs something a bit more bullet proof.

Comment: As buggy as Notes can be at times I find it hard to believe @TextToNumber is the problem here.  Maybe the text needs to be wrapped in @Trim first?

Answer (score 1):

Because the text field has numeric values, they are still treated as literal string. So, the easiest way I have found to format them and avoiding @Errors' is to pad them with leading zeroes as well and continue to treat them as a string.

The good thing about this solution is that we're still dealing with strings. No mucking about with data type conversions where you may have data that cannot be converted into a number.

So put this into your column formula and set the sorting options as ascending or descending as you require:

```
MaxSize := 10;
len := @Length(@trim(yourField));
Pad := MaxSize - Len;
@Repeat("0";pad) + @trim(yourField);
```

Make sure that your "MaxSize" value is greater than the length of any value it receives. From the sample you've provided, 4 looks like it will do the trick.

(As per Ken's suggestion), if the appearance of the padded column to the user is not appealing, you can make this column a hidden, sorted column and then present the original unformatted (and unsorted) column to the user so it appears in a numerical order.

Comment: Good workaround.  Note that this could be added as a hidden column for sorting purposes if you don't want the padded numbers to show in the view.

Comment: @Ken. Thanks for that, have updated the answer include your comment as well.